# Asp Net Core MVC RedirectToAction not working (No TempData)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using `RedirectToAction` after a Login to `/Home/Index`, but is not working. Also, `/Home/Index` is `[Authorized]`. I find this issue amazing and couldn't find a way to solve this. It's a pretty strange behaviour, as in .Net Framework it works as expected. Also, I have no errors either on Server or Client.

This is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    return View(model);
}

private IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) return Redirect(returnUrl);
    else return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

In the response headers, I see the following:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/Account/Login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Found
...
Location: /
```

Using `Redirect` it works as I want and I have a Location: `/Home/Index`. I don't know whats is happen.

I searched about and found some issues with `TempData` and Cookies, but I don't use it.

I you need more code, just ask for it. I will post it.

Comment: That's right, it was failing cause I had the BrowserDirectory middleware, as it wasn't using the full route. You can post an answer, I will accept it.